# SQL to Excel table in VBA using IF EXISTS complains "Invalid SQL statement"

Tags: sql, vba, excel, ms-access, adodb

I am using **SQL** in **VBA** inside **MS Excel** to query a spreadsheet.  I want to check for a record's existence, and either update or insert the record as appropriate.  This calls for:

```
IF EXISTS (condition) UPDATE ELSE INSERT
```

The "Test" portion doesn't work, and raises an error.  In debugging, I have eliminated all Excel elements from the query, resulting in the following code:

```
Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim recset As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim scmd As String
scmd = "IF EXISTS (SELECT 'Test')"
scmd = scmd + "SELECT 'Found' "

conn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
"Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name & ";" & _
"Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"
conn.Execute (scmd)

conn.Close
```

This generates the SQL statement:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 'Test') SELECT 'Found'
```

The resulting error is:

> Invalid SQL statement; expected 'DELETE', 'INSERT', 'PROCEDURE', 'SELECT', or 'UPDATE'.

I tested the same statement in MS SSMS, and it worked properly.  Having eliminated both my Excel spreadsheet and the SQL statement as problems, it seems the problem is in a quirk of VBA.  How do I fix this?

For what it's worth, the connection string works properly for pure `SELECT` queries in my project.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! What's your exact SQL statement? Does that `Test` qualify as a column name or a table name? Can you use `[]` with proper column and table names and try the query?

Comment: The ACE engine does not implement `IF`, iirc `IIF()` works

Comment: @bonCodigo In my simplified statement, I am explicitly selecting the string `Test`.

Comment: @AlexK.:  That didn't change anything; I got the same error.

Comment: So what's the rewritten SQL your using? you cant use `IF EXISTS`

Comment: @AlexK.: Why does `IF EXISTS` not work in this case?  I've found quite a few related questions that use it.

Comment: Your limited to ACE/Jet SQL which has no control of flow constructs.  `IF EXISTS ` would work in SQL Server but not Access or anything else Jet driven.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the ACE OleDb provider to interact with the spreadsheet.  That means you can use only SQL features that provider supports for your data source.  `IF EXISTS` is not supported in this situation.

However, there may be an even more basic problem.  I don't believe it's possible to alter the contents of a spreadsheet with SQL executed from ACE OleDb.

Comment: Ah, that would explain it.  Can I use a different provider to query (and update!) the other spreadsheet?

Comment: I'm not aware of any SQL (DML) method to alter a spreadsheet's content.

Comment: Bummer.  :(  I had been exploring SQL because updating the target spreadsheet through automation (open the XLS file, find target row, copy data, save & close, lather-rinse-repeat) had a big performance impact.

Comment: I feel your pain.  I'm primarily a database person.  Maybe another spreadsheet person can offer you a less painful alternative.

Comment: I'm a software person forced into a spreadsheet position.  Though I did come up with the idea of updating only the one row of interest, with some thanks to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim recset As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim scmd As String

scmd = "SELECT * from [Sheet1$]"

conn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
    "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name & ";" & _
    "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"
recset.ActiveConnection = conn
recset.Open scmd

If Not recset.EOF And Not recset.BOF Then
    Debug.Print "found"
End If

conn.Close
```

This should do the trick. Basically, this is your code with a minor change.
As Alex-K noted, the Excel engine cannot evaluate `if` statements for your. An SQL server would be able to. But within Excel you'll have to restrict your SQL language and evaluate the `if` yourself as shown above.

Comment: And thanks for catching the missing space.  My original query does have that space.